# Code of nodejs using mongoose works on local machine but on VPS it doen't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, debian

This works on windows 7 localhost:

```
var User = mongoose.model(userDBName, userSchema);
```

But it gives this error for Debian VPS:

```
/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:28

      return pluralize(name.toLowerCase());
                            ^
        TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
            at exports.toCollectionName (/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:28:25)
            at Mongoose.model (/home/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:361:46)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXX/nodejs/js/dbbase.js:54:21)
            at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
            at require (module.js:380:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/home/XXX/nodejs/js/db_read.js:1:76)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was the name is really undefined, due to userDBName is undefined. It relative with 'nconf' and config.json. Just incorrect way to this file.